# want to know whether the email or the username already exists [mysql, php]

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to if the username or the email already exists in database

```
$prep_stmt = "SELECT `id` FROM `members` WHERE `email` = ? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($prep_stmt);

    if ($stmt) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

            if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
                return "A user with this email address already exists";
            }
     } else {
         return "Database error";
     }
```

now i could do the same for the username, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do it with mysql

i tried to do it like this...

```
SELECT `id` FROM `members` WHERE `email` = "user@user.com" OR `username` = "testuser" LIMIT 1
```

but if the email and the username are identical it show without the LIMIT TAG 2 id's and I don't know which one is for email or for the username and if I make the call with the LIMIT TAG it shows me one result and still I don't know if it is the username or the email which is identical

Comment: I would make the fields unique, both email and username. Instead of using LIMIT clauses.

Comment: `SELECT email, username` instead of id and compare them to the email and username variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use:

```
SELECT `id`, 
       IF(`email` = "user@user.com",1,0) as foundMail,
       IF`username` = "testuser"   ,1,0) as foundUser
FROM `members` 
WHERE `email` = "user@user.com" 
  OR `username` = "testuser"
```

foundMail will be 1 if Mail matched, foundUser will be 1 if User matched

regards

Comment: This can work but you'll still have to iterate the result set if both conditions are true for different users.

Comment: Optionally you can sort the results `ORDER BY foundMail DESC, foundUser DESC` so that results that match both conditions appear first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<?php
// you should use * for all columns selected instead of id
$stmt="SELECT * FROM members WHERE email=:txtemail LIMIT 1";
$calldata = $db->prepare ($stmt);
$calldata->bindParam(':txtemail', $txtemail, PDO::PARAM_STR,27);
$calldata->execute();
$result = $calldata->fetchColumn();     
if (htmlspecialchars($result) == false){
    //some script if not found
    }
else{
    //some script if found or exists
}
?>
```